# Change background color of even cells in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm having trouble changing the background color of even cells in a tableView. When the view loads the cells are colored correctly but as I scroll, the background color goes to white or all light grey.

Should I update the background color another way?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("gradeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if ( indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to set the background color back to the original color if the row isn't even

Comment: Or in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot that cells are being reused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code snippet.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("gradeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }else{
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // set your default color
    }

    return cell
  }
```